# получить видео через php

Tags: php, html5

Здравствуйте, необходимо для html5 плеера () обращаться на php страницу, что бы та возвращала видео, т.е. в php будут обрабатываться определенные условия, и выдватся нужное видео. При том видео может быть размером до 1 гб. что бы не застряло в памяти, как можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно через php-функцию readfile, она позволяет читать файл по частям, а не сразу целиком.